# How do I style a div with inner floats to expand horizontally to allow all inner floating divs to fit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically, I have a content box with some floating items:

`html`

```
<div class="contentBox">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

`css`

```
.contentBox {
    overflow-x:scroll;
}
.item {
    float:left;
}
```

I want the box to expand in width to let as many items as I add to it to fit, floating left (which means the elements get pushed to the right). But instead it only goes as wide as the page before the items drop down because of having no room. I want it to continue on outside of the page.

How do I do this?

I'm thinking I'll need to use some JavaScript, but I'd rather a pure CSS solution if it's possible.

Comment: You might want `display: table` and `display: table-cell`

Comment: Well, one solution is to use `display: inline-block` instead of `float` and add `white-space: nowrap;` to the parent element - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nJydR/65/)

Comment: @AndrewDunai I just tried adding `display:table` to the parent, and `display:table-cell` to the items, but that didn't seem to work, can you demonstrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `white-space: nowrap` on parent container with inline-block child elements:

```
.contentBox {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.item {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vo8202uy/

```js
$('button').click(function() {
    $('.contentBox').append('<div class="item">' + ($('.item').length+1) + '</div>');
});
```

```css
.contentBox {
    overflow-x:scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.item {
    width: 50px;
    background: coral;
    margin-right: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contentBox">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
<button>Add more</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `display: table-cell` for `.item`.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/andunai/fq201q8b/

Answer (score 0):

Here you GO :)
Only add this on you button click.

```
$('button').click(function() {
  var item = $('.item').length + 1;
   $('.contentBox').append('<div class="item">' + item + '</div>');

   var w = window.innerWidth;
   var l = $(".contentBox div").length + 1;
   $(".contentBox div").each(function(){
        $(this).css("width", w/l);
   });
});
```

Check this JSFiddle Link
http://jsfiddle.net/DynamicRemo/8krcm0x6/